# Having difficulties converting a string into decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Thanks for taking the time to assist me with my problem.

In the code I'm writing, I'm iterating through a table, I get the appropriate values (confirmed it using the debugger) and I'm parsing them to the appropriate types before and finally I add them to an Object to be serialized into XML.

However, I bumped into a problem and that is I can't seem to find a way to parse the string into a decimal value. Take a look:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, styles, out date))
{
   decimal LastValue;
   string vrednost = String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 
                       row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]").InnerText);

   if (Decimal.TryParse(vrednost, out LastValue))
      list.Add(new StockEntry
                  {
                     Date = date,
                     PoslednaCena = LastValue
                     ...
                  }
```

Note that the value of vrednost is 4.451,00 and I suspect that if I convert it to 4,451.00 it will get parsed.

I've succeeded in parsing date into the appropriate datetime value. However, the value of LastValue is always 0. I've exhausted all the resources that I know of. Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The value of `vrednost` should be 4,451.00 not 4.451,00 based on the `String.Format` you are using.

Comment: So what does vrednost look like after the string format?

Comment: @ swdevman, the value of vrednost is 4.451,00.

Comment: @hogan, the funny thing is that vrednost's value is the same after the string format. It does not change. Do you reckon if I switch the places of ',' and '.' that might solve my problem?

Comment: But what does 4.451,00 mean? Is it supposed to be 4.451? Or does the period separate thousands and the comma represent the decimal place in your culture? I suspect the answer involves the Globalization culture you parse with.

Comment: @Dragan - should not matter, the string format you are passing is for a number and you are passing it a string, so I would not expect it to change.  string formats don't care about `:` and `,`

Comment: @ ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ The format i'm gettin is 4.000,00 and I'm fine with it. The thing is that it won't get parsed..

Answer (score 1):

This formatting will do nothing because you can't format strings like this. You have to use parse method with additional parameters and specify your own format

```
string s2 = "4.451,00";    
NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
var d = decimal.Parse(s2, numberFormatInfo);
```

Comment: then, what do you want to get in result?

Comment: you get the decimal value, it does not have formatting. If you want to change the format - convert decimal value to string with new one using string.format or decomal.tostring methods

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem might be due to the culture used for the parsing. Try using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for your parsing. It should work with "," as thousands separator and "." as decimal separator.

```
Decimal.TryParse(vrednost, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out LastValue);
```

If you want to swap them you could use another culture. Italian, for instance, works with your format (not sure about the others), so your code for "4.451,00" would look like:

```
Decimal.TryParse(vrednost, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it"), out LastValue);
```

If you want to use a custom culture instead of forcing some culture which does what you want you can simply create your NumberFormatInfo class and pass it to the parse method.

```
NumberFormatInfo decimalNumber = new NumberFormatInfo();
decimalNumber.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
decimalNumber.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
Decimal.TryParse(vrednost, NumberStyles.Number, decimalNumber, out LastValue);
```

Comment: I tried it with both it-IT and mk-MK (macedonia) and it returns 4451 which is still a progress considering LastValue always returned 0.. Thanks tho.

Comment: I changed my answer including the use of a custom culture that you could define on your own depending on the result that you want to get. This way you could avoid the nasty string.format at the beginning of your code.

Comment: I don't get it. Actually decimal do returns a decimal, not an int. I think that your misunderstanding might come from the fact that a decimal number is not formatted by default when you print it or convert it to string, so a number without decimal places doesn't have neither decimal separators nor group separators. If you provide to the parse function a number with decimal digits you should see that it's not an int. If you want to format it in a proper way you could use either string.format or its tostring method with a proper formatting expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your *row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]").InnerText* is a **string** and you are trying to format it like a decimal.

Try parsing it directly:

```
decimal LastValue;
string vrednost = row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]").InnerText;

if (Decimal.TryParse(vrednost, out LastValue))
```

Check your cultureinfo at first and set it appropriately.

```
CultureInfo MyUsersCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine("The culture: "+ MyUsersCulture.Name);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
ConsoleWriteLine("The culture: " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Ibram, thanks for participating in the disucussion. That's what I first tried. The thing is if I try to parse it this way, it takes me straight to the else clause. It won't parse the string with format => 0.000,00.

Comment: what is your application running for cultureinfo? and is your data always is such a format?

Comment: my current culture is en-US. That's the exact format I want the decimal to be in.

Comment: did you removed your string.format? remove it, set your currentculture to e.g. german de-DE, tryparse with decimal.

Comment: sometimes it is better to have a short break before continuing. look outside, listen to the birds, drink your coffee. then you will find the missing point :)