# string to double parsing error

Tags: c#, .net, double

i have the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("mk-MK");
        string s2 = "4.434,00";

        double d;

        if (Double.TryParse(s2, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d))
        {
            //String.Format("{0:0.0,00}", d);
            Console.WriteLine(d + " Type of: " + d.GetType());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ne go parsirashe");
        }

        String.Format("{0:0.0,00}", d);
        Console.WriteLine(d);


        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", d));


        //Console.WriteLine(s2.GetType().ToString());
        //Console.ReadLine();

        //String.Format("{0:0.0,00}"
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is: 4434 Type of: System.Double
               4434

Why isn't the value of d in the format of : 4.434,00 ? Can you please help me with this? I've sent couple of hours trying to figure this out before trying to reach out to you guys. Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having difficulties converting a string into decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114253/having-difficulties-converting-a-string-into-decimal)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 - definitely not a dupe, as this question is culture related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are discarding your formatted string - you are not assigning it to a string and simply outputting the double to the console (which would call `ToString()` on it).

Try this:

```
string forDisplay = string.Format("{0:0.0,00}", d);
Console.WriteLine(forDisplay);
```

Or, even shorter:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.0,00}", d));
```

---

Update:

In order to format the string according to your culture, you will need to use the [`Format` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) that takes an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) (i.e. a culture) and ensure that the format string uses the right characters for the different parts (`,` for *standard* thousands separator and `.` for *standard* decimal separator - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for the meanings of each such character in a format string):

```
var res = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0,0.00}", d);
Console.WriteLine(forDisplay);
```

Result:

```
4.434,00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the output now is: 4434,00 instead of 4.434,00. How do I fix that?

Comment: @Dragan - Are you sure that the parse to double of the string was correct?

Comment: well it passed the if clause, so it should be parsed correctly. I'm really puzzled as to why it would not display it in the right format. Thanks for taking interest in my prob Oded. Appreaciate it!

Comment: Oded, thank you so much!! I hope I can one day return the favour! I figured the last part on my own and came back to answer it when I saw you've beat me to it :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You meant to do:

```
string formatted = String.Format("{0:0.0,00}", d);
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

`string.Format` returns a string -- it cannot affect the formatting of a `double`, since doubles have no formatting at all. Doubles only store the raw numeric value (as bits, internally).

Comment: Thanks. For your answer, however the output now is: 4434,00 instead of 4.434,00. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `.` and `,` around the wrong way, if I'm understanding what you're trying to do.

If you read the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) page on MSDN, you can see that you need to use `,` for the thousands separator, and `.` for the decimal separator, and (the important part) *the target culture is irrelevant here*. The format is always the same, regardless of the current culture.

So what you want to use is:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0,0.00}", d);
```

Then the output is:

```
4434 Type of: System.Double
4.434,00
```

Comment: Thank you! The question has already been answered but I'm going to upvote your asnwer because it's corrent. Thanks for the clarification regarding the formatting. Cheers!